# How to pass List from JSP to ACtion Class

Tags: jsp, struts

Good day!

I want to convert my code into STRUTS.. and i tried not using the getParameter in my Action Class..
But I can't pass the information from JSP to Action Class without using the getParameter.

JSP:

```
 <html:form action="EditExam">
                <input type = "hidden" name = applicantNumber value="${applicantForm.applicantNumber}"  >

                <table>
                    <c:forEach var="exam" items="${examList}">
                        <input type = "hidden" name ="examId" value="${exam.examId}"  >
                       <tr>
                           <td>Exam Type: &nbsp</td>       <td><input type="text" value="${exam.examName}" name="examType" readonly ="true"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>Date: </td>                 <td><input type="text" value="${exam.examDate}" name="examDate" class="date"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>Result: </td>               
                           <td>
                                <select name = examResult> 
                                    <option value="Pass" ${exam.examResult == 'Pass' ? 'selected' : ''}>Pass</option>
                                    <option value="Fail" ${exam.examResult == 'Fail' ? 'selected' : ''}>Fail</option>
                                    <option value="" ${exam.examResult == '' ? 'selected' : ''}></option>
                                </select>   
                           </td>   
                       </tr>
                        <tr><td>&nbsp</td><td> &nbsp</td></tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" class="saveButton" value="SAVE">

            </html:form>
```

ACTION CLASS:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String forward = "success";

        ApplicantForm applicantForm = (ApplicantForm)form;
        int applicantNumber = applicantForm.getApplicantNumber();   

        String examDate[] = request.getParameterValues("examDate");
        String examResult[] = request.getParameterValues("examResult");
        String examId[] = request.getParameterValues("examId");
            //MORE CODES AFTER...
```

**My problem is:**
How can I pass the data from JSP to Action Class without using the getparameter.

TO CONSIDER:

1. My Exam is a list...
2. The EDIT Button is outside the loop... so all changes inside the loop should be captured.. (Do i need to pass the ArrayList? How can i catch it on the Action FOrm?)

You're reply would be highly appreciated. THANK YOU.

Comment: did my suggestion answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can transfer data from the browser (html, the result of jsp) to the server with the HTTP protocol, which transfers only textual request parameters.

So you have to use `request.getParameter[Values](..)`. If you need a `List`, you can use `Arrays.asList(array)`.

I think struts should have some form of binding, so wherever you specify your input parameters, you can try specifying a `List`, and perhaps struts will populate it. (but it will still use `request.getParameterValues(..)` under the hood)

Answer (score 3):

HTML/JSP doesn't understand java objects such as lists. They only deal with pure strings/numbers or bytestreams.

So you have to use

```
request.getParameter("paramName");
```

or if you need a map, you can use

```
Map < String, String[] > queryParamsMap = (Map < String, String[] > )request.getParameterMap();
```

From the map, you can directly get an array of your specific parameter. By using for example

```
String[] paramArray = queryParamsMap.get("myParam");
```